# Calculate week of the month a file was last written to PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell, backup

Is there any way to calculate in what week a file was last written to?

The situation is as follows:
I have a lot of Full SQL backup files (.BAK files), written only on sundays, but... I only need to keep the files written to in the 4th(or last) week of the month (not only the current month, but the month in which the file was last written to).

So the search would be something like; check if files are written to in the last week of the month and delete everything that is not equal to the last week of the month.

Is there any way I can do this with PowerShell?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want: Do you want the last week of a month or the date of the last sunday of a month? So, do you want to keep the full backup or the last week of backups?

Comment: maybe you want most recent backup in each month?

Comment: @Ocaso Protal I want to keep the full backup, but only the one that was created in the last week of the month. So for this month it would be the one created on sunday 25th of august.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$path = "C:\mySearchFolder"
get-childitem $path |
    where-object{$_.CreationTime.AddDays(7).Month -ne $_.CreationTime.Month} |
    remove-item $_.FullPath;
```

What I'm doing here is comparing the month of the `CreationTime` to the month of `CreationTime` plus 7 days. If one week later than `CreationTime` is in a different month, then it's the last Sunday of the month.